# Setting up redis cluster on Mac OS X via create-cluster script

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I want to set-up a redis cluster on Mac via the `create-cluster` script as mentioned in [Cluster tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#creating-a-redis-cluster-using-the-create-cluster-script). I am not able to locate the create-cluster script on Mac.

I am using `redis 3.2.0` installed via `brew` on `Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G31)`.

Can someone let me know where `create-cluster` script is located in Mac?

Comment: https://redis.io/topics/chttps://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorialluster-tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was not able to create cluster via the redis installed via brew. So I did the following:-

- Downloaded the latest version from Redis from [here](http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.5.tar.gz). In my case Redis 3.2.5
- Then followed the installation instruction as mentioned [here](http://redis.io/download#installation).
- `create-cluster` is located inside `$DOWNLOAD/redis-3.2.5/utils/create-cluster` where `$DOWNLOAD` is the location where I downloaded and untar the redis.

Comment: create-cluster should exist with brew installation

Comment: @K'' Where would that be found?

Comment: @wmute i'm on high sierra 10.13.4 and i can find it under /Users/username/opt/redis-4.0.2/utils/create-cluster

Comment: Interesting. I don't see that on high sierra. I ended up using a Docker container which was much easier.

Comment: FYI, to run through __creat-cluster__ use `sh create-cluster start`, more info go https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial and navigate to __Creating a Redis Cluster using the create-cluster script__

Comment: Broken old redis tgz link. Use https://redis.io/download

Answer (score 8):

I'm on Mac 10.15.5, have installed the Redis 6.0.5 via brew, and don't see **create-cluster** script too within such installation.

So, I followed the following steps:

1. Donwload the latest manual installation, i.e. redis-%version%.tar from the official site.
2. Copy the folder **utils** from dowloaded archive to my local redis destination folder, i.e. /usr/local/Cellar/redis/6.0.5 in my case.
3. Change create-cluster file. There are settings inside: BIN_PATH="**../../src/**" to BIN_PATH="**../../bin/**" in order this cluster script can find the related redis scripts.
4. Follow the guide https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

For me it works now.